# How do I remove files that I have downloaded from the Dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The problem is that the dashHome shows all the files and icons that I have downloaded and used and I want to remove them from the dashHome. Can any one help how can I do it without nu-installing the applications.

Answer (score 6):

Open **Privacy settings** from Dash and turn off the **record activity for files.**

[image: Screenshot]